# How do I check if one of two radio buttons is checked with PHP?

Tags: php, html

How do I check if one of two radio buttons is checked with PHP?

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <b>Yes or No?</b><br>
    Yes <input type="radio" name="template" value="Yes"> 
    NO <input type="radio" name="template" value="No"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Skicka internlogg">

</form>
```

I don't want one of this two radio buttons to be checked from the beginning. I want an if-statement that continue with the code if one of them are checked by the user. And if not I want to print an error code like "Please fill the whole form" or something. How?

I then want to check for multiple statements from radio buttons and text boxes, how?

`if($_POST['sr'] && $_POST['relevant'] && if(isset($_POST['article'])) && if(isset($_POST['template'])) && $_POST['text']) {}` ?????

Comment: `isset($_POST['template'])` will check if any of the 2 is checked. If none of them is, it will be null  (isset will return false).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP multiple radio buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656260/php-multiple-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon form submission, check to see if the POST variable "template" is not set using [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

The `!` in front of `isset` means "not". Therefore, it is checking to see if "template" **is not** set.

You should check each element of your form separately so you can provide constructive feedback to the end-user on what they need to do to resolve the error message. This is considered **best practice** and something you should do on any form, regardless how big or small.

```
<?php
// Form submitted
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
    // CHECK FOR ERRORS

    // Check for radio button value
    if(!isset($_POST['template'])) {
        // No value for template, show error message
        $e['template'] = "<p><strong>Please select Yes or No.</strong></p>";
    }

    // Check the value of text box
    if(!isset($_POST['relevant'])) {
        $e['relevant'] = "<p><strong>Please fill out the Relevant field.</strong></p>";
    }

    // If no errors occurred, finish processing the form
    if(!is_array($e)) {
        // Do stuff (db update, email send out, etc.)

        // Show thank you message
        echo "<p>Thank you. We have received your submission.</p>";
        exit();
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <?php echo $e['relevant']; ?>
    <p><label for="relevant">Relevant:</label><input type="text" name="relevant" id="relevant" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['relevant']); ?>" /></p>

    <?php echo $e['template']; ?>
    <p>Yes or No?</p>
    <p><label for="yes">Yes</label><input type="radio" name="template" id="yes" value="Yes" <?php if($_POST['template'] == "Yes") { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> /></p>
    <p><label for="no">No</label><input type="radio" name="template" id="no" value="No" <?php if($_POST['template'] == "No") { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> /></p>

    <p><input type="submit" name="send" value="Skicka internlogg" /></p>
</form>
```

**EDIT:** To address you wanting to do the check all at once, which **you should not get in the habit of doing**, you could do something like this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['template']) || !isset($_POST['relevant']) || !isset($_POST['sr']) || ... ) {
    $error = "<p>Please fill out all form fields.</p>";
}
```

Then echo the error out in the form as in my example above.

Comment: Why does not this works?

`if($_POST['sr'] && $_POST['relevant'] && if(isset($_POST['article'])) && if(isset($_POST['template'])) && $_POST['text']) {}`

I want to check for multiple statement at once.

Comment: There looks to be more values in your form than you shared in your example. I **would not** check for all values at once; Check for them separately so you can show a specific error message to the user, removing any confusion in their mind to what they need to do to fix the problem.

Comment: Okey, I know that's better. But don't want to in this project! :P It's a to simple form to do anything wrong. Do you know how to check for all? It's just two text boxes and these radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks, that a nice way to go. :) But how do I check for all at once? I will mark this as the solution, just need to know. :)

Comment: Hmm, || = OR? I want to check if all fields are filled. I tried with: `if(isset($_POST['sr']) && isset($_POST['relevant']) && isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['article']) && isset($_POST['template']))` but now it continues with the code if just the radio buttons are marked. :S

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen Have you tested your answer? There are a few problems you know, which will generate parse errors. Just thought you would like to know and tell the OP as well, what will be needed to fix this.

Comment: This one worked: `if($_POST['sr'] && $_POST['relevant'] && $_POST['text'] && isset($_POST['article']) && isset($_POST['template']))` :D Thanks for all help! :D

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for catching the missing semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(isset($_POST['template'])){
    $template = $_POST['template'];

    //do more stuff
}
else{
    echo "Please fill the whole form."; //error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isset` function in your php code.

```
if (isset($_POST['template'])){
    // Yes or No selected.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

To check all POST values at once, you can create an array of required fields and loop through that.

```
$required_fields = array("name", "address", "phone", "email");
foreach ($require_fields as $field) {
    if (!strlen($_POST[$field])) {
    echo "$field cannot be empty";
    }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4496301/1415724

---

---

### Original

In using my example below, radio buttons need to be treated as an array using `[]` when using `foreach`, as in `name="template[]"` for all radio buttons used. Otherwise, there will be an error such as `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

This enables you to use it in another way, such as checkboxes should you decide to use that instead of radio buttons in another application.

#### Here is an example:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['template'];

if(isset($_POST['template'])) {

echo "You chose: <br>";
echo "<ul>";

foreach ($name as $template){

echo "<li>" .$template."</li>";

}

echo "</ul>";

} // isset

else {

echo "You did not make a choice.";

}

?>

<form action="" method="post">

    <b>Yes or No?</b><br>
    Yes <input type="radio" name="template[]" value="Yes"> 
    NO <input type="radio" name="template[]" value="No"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Using `template[]` would be true if he was using checkboxes. With radio buttons, only one radio button in the group can be selected at a given time.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen Not when using a `foreach` in my example. Otherwise this error message will appear `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: There is no reason to use `foreach` to check radio button values. You are over complicating a very simple check.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen I was supplying an example and it's useable, tested and working. Just like your answer, is one of many ways to do it. From mine, the OP can also use it for checkboxes also. Since the OP did not give us a handler to work with, is what I came up with, just like you, which is good also. ;-)

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen It seems that the OP now added some new information to his/her question. So, "the plot thickens", as it were. These types of questions always end up having people's answer being wrong. I take this from experience.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isSet($_POST['template']) && $_POST['template'])
{
   // dsth
}
else
   echo 'Please fill the whole form';
```

You need to edit your PHP code ^

Comment: From the OP, "I don't want one of this two radio buttons to be checked from the beginning."